# How can I redirect the error stream when calling powershell.exe using -File parameter

Tags: powershell, io-redirection, sccm

I'm executing a powershell script during an OS deployment task sequence using SCCM. Due to idiosyncrasies with this ecosystem I have to call the script with syntax like this (to the best of my experimentation):

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "w:\scripts\script.ps1" -param1 "%param1%" -param2 "%param2%"
```

This works fine, but I wanted to capture the output of this and any error messages it throws. Normally I would do something like:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "w:\scripts\script.ps1" -param1 "%param1%" -param2 "%param2%" > "%logfile" 2>&1
```

However, per the documentation, the -file parameter must be the last parameter, and the above triggers an error since it's trying to interpret the ">" as a parameter.

Obviously I can't use:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "w:\scripts\script.ps1" -param1 "%param1%" -param2 "%param2%" | out-file "%logfile"
```

because this is a commandline engine, so even if the pipe wasn't interpreted as a parameter, out-file would be interpreted as an executable, not a cmdlet. And even if that worked, out-file doesn't capture the error stream.

Is my only option to output the script's internal logging to a file/transcript, within the script? I feel like there should be a way to do this all from the executable call. The parsing behavior of the -file parameter makes sense, but is obnoxiously limiting.

Thanks,
== Matt

Comment: Have you tried to use `-command` parameter? Something like `-command "& {. 'w:\scripts\script.ps1' -param1 -param2 | out-file 'logfile'}"`

Comment: @montonero It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure I've tried that and it didn't work for me. I'll have to give it another shot. However, now that I'm looking through some of my other scripts and steps in this task sequence, I see that I do actually use the trailing ">" successfully elsewhere. I believe both of these oddities have something to do with a difference in the way the task sequence engine handles interpreting/executing ```cmd /c powershell.exe``` versus just ```powershell.exe``` I'll have to re-examine this...

Comment: You could also try to add [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Host/Start-Transcript?view=powershell-5.1) to your ps1 script.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comment to the question, this was apparently due to an idiosyncrasy with SCCM's task sequence engine, which somehow causes `cmd /c powershell.exe` to be interpreted differently than `powershell.exe`.

Adding the `cmd /c` solved the issue of `>` being interpreted as a -file parameter input, rather than as a stream redirection operator.

In fact, I rediscovered that I do use syntax like:
`powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "w:\scripts\script.ps1" -param1 "%param1%" -param2 "%param2%" > "%logfile" 2>&1`
successfully outside of the task sequence engine, in other powershell scripts and batch scripts, so it's not a powershell nor commandline interpreter issue.